# Is it possible to follow Javascript redirect in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using [node.js request library](https://github.com/mikeal/request) which can follow HTTP redirects but is there a way to follow Javascript redirect such as this?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; /subpage"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href = '/subpage/';
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

The only thing I can think of is to test for the `window.location.href` value in the head of the response and if true, follow it.

Is there some better solution?

Comment: There probably is if you use a headless browser and parse the javascript

Comment: Yes, using something like phantom.js is an option but this is quite an exceptional case so I was wondering if there is something else I could do on node.js side to solve this.

Comment: I recommend using phantomjs to fetch the page. Basically you'll need to simulate a normal user behaviour/flow as close as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `window.location.href` is not the only way to do a javascript redirect, so the hack you suggest would not work in every case.

Also, if the new url is a variable  (eg: `window.location.url = some_variable`) you will not catch it.

The most elegant way to be sure to follow any javascript redirect is to use a webdriver such as [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).

The advantage of this solution is that it will follow *any* html/javascript redirect. The disadvantage is it requires setup, and the execution of the webdriver can be slow.